# .htaccess Issues with 404 and URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an `.htaccess` with the following code inside it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

The purpose of this is to

- Remove the `.php` extension from the url
- Rewrite the url so that `POST` data will appear after the slash i.e. if the original url were to be `website.com/sheet?username=bob`, this would be rewritten to `website.com/sheet/bob`
- Redirect to a custom 404 page when the specific url given is not found

This code performs fine while developing locally via WAMP, and I am able to see different info based on the `<user>` value of `website.com/sheet/<user>`.

When I go to upload the changes to the live site, the code no longer works, and shows `website.com/sheet/bob` as my custom 404 page.

Is my `.htaccess` wrong? Sorry, I'm pretty inexperienced with `.htaccess`.

---

**Edit** If I remove the `.htaccess`, if I attempt to go to `website.com/sheet.php`, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@website.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This does **not** produce an `error` file in my document root though, so I'm unsure exactly how to see the issue :s

---

Thanks

Comment: If you completely remove your version of htaccess from the server, is the server behaviour different? Just to check if it actually is the .htaccess you're using.

Comment: I removed the `.htaccess` and a different issue occurred. I added an edit to my original post (for other peoples' visibility)

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to use rewriting for what is the job of the `ErrorDocument` directive ...?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by "For what is the job of the `ErrorDocument` directive", but the url rewriting is so that users are able to go to `website.com/sheet/<user>`, which is serving the purpose of showing different sets of data based on that user while only having to reference the single page of `website.com/sheet`. Not sure if I answered your question correctly

Comment: That last error. Often there is something wrong with your php config.

Comment: I was able to verify the php versions match, and turned up all of the logging and `display_errors`. I verified all of the php options as well (to the best of my knowledge), but am still seeing the internal error. Maybe I will need to contact the web host.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by modifying my `.htaccess` to something else I found on SO. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with the `.htaccess`.

Originally:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

Now:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!404\.php)$ - [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ ./$1.php [L]
```

I'm not very good at `.htaccess` files so I coulnd't tell you what the exact issue was, but this change seems to accomplish what I was aiming for without giving any of the errors.